# Firestore query and filtering how to do for leaderboard

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a task app with flutter and I'm showing a leaderboard with the 15 best players from day, 15 best of week and 15 best of month. The users can filter by day week or month and im showing a list of the results to them, ordered by people with most finished tasks.

Now instead of doing 3 queries with day, week, month, I planned to do a month query and filter for week and day by client. This is my query:

```
Timestamp get timeLimit {
    final limit = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 30));
    return Timestamp.fromDate(limit);
  }

    getRanking() async {
        List<Data> _rankingResult = [];
    
    
        QuerySnapshot snapshot = 
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('tasks')
        .where('dateWhenProofed', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: timeLimit)
        .limit(15) <- what about that?
        .get();
        
        snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
          Data data = Data.fromJson(document.data());
          _rankingResult.add(data);
          _rankingResult.sort((a, b) => b.finishedTasksCount.compareTo(a.finishedTasksCount));
        });

    notifier.rankingList = _rankingResult;

  }
```

Im wondering about the `.limit()`. I need only the 15 best results for each filter, but what if we have 1000 documents here, how exactly does the `limit()` work? Does it check the whole firestore documents from task collection or does it only check the first 15? My goal is to get the 15 highest values out of this to present.

Also im wondering if we have 15 results here and I filter it clientside to week only, how can I make sure to also get 15 results of the week there? Maybe I don't have to limit the month query then? Would be nice if someone has an idea about this.

EDIT:

Well I'm not 100% sure (someone should confirm that) but it looks like with `limit()` in the query, we are cutting data which would be in the top 15 list. I think we can avoid that by adding the `orderBy()` parameter. Query now would look like this:

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = 
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('tasks')
    .where('dateWhenProofed', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: timeLimit)
    .orderBy('dateWhenProofed', descending: true) <--- added this line
    .limit(15)
    .get();

snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
              Data data = Data.fromJson(document.data());
              _rankingResult.add(data);
              _rankingResult.sort((a, b) => b.finishedTasksCount.compareTo(a.finishedTasksCount));
            });
```

With this applied, we can make sure to get all the data. The only thing which doesnt fit right now is by filtering to week and day only now, because  we said in the query, that the `timeLimit` is 30days. How can we do week and day data filtering best practise now?