# Firestore pricing model case

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to understand the firebase pricing model and I stumbled over this. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing

> **Queries other than document reads**
>
> For queries other than document reads, such as a request for a list of collection IDs, you are billed for one document read. If fetching the complete set of results requires more than one request (for example, if you are using pagination), you are billed once per request.*

Let's say Im fetching 10 profiles from a `profiles` collection (10.000 documents) randomly `limit(10)` it would cost me 10 reads.

```
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('profiles')
    .limit(10)
    .get()
    .then(...)
```

Now I want to show my 10 results in the UI and I also want to show the clients a heart icon which is filled if the client liked the profile or not. I would fetch the user data and check if the user liked one of the 10 profiles. I already learned storing the user specific data in the same collection `profiles` doesn't make sense, lets say we are saving it in a `users` collection subcollection called `profilelikes`:

```
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc('userId')
        .collection('profilelikes')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
              querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
                if () {
                  // check if profiles from list matches userprofile document
                }
              })
            });
```

What does it mean for this case exactly? Lets say the user has 5000 documents inside the `profilelikes` Im searching in 5000 documents if 10 of them are matching or not. Let's say 2 of them are matching:

How many costs do we have here?

**First Query**: 10 reads because we have 10 results here
**Second Query**: ???

Comment: Just a recommendation, if you don't want to fret over read/write counts stick with the Realtime Database because it has a much simpler billing structure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i think in my case the realtime database doesnt make sense to me because it is deep not flat, since i have a lot and hierarchical data and the realtime data does the billing on bandwith amount it reads the whole tree even if i dont need it. real time database is good for simple data structure. Anyways it would be interesting if somebody could point out what happens to the provided case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chapter you point out in your question actually covers "**queries other than document reads**". For example with the Firestore REST API you can list the collection Ids, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/listCollectionIds) in the API doc. The same with the Admin SDKs, see for example the [`listCollections()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#listCollections) method.

In your case, you are actually reading documents.

- So the first query will cost 10 reads, "because we have 10 results" as you said.
- The second query (`collection('users').doc('userId').collection('profilelikes').get()`) will cost 5000 reads since you are querying the entire (sub)collection which contains 5000 documents.

**Conclusion:** you should most probably adapt your data model (denormalization?) in order to avoid fetching an entire subcollection.

---

PS: It's worth noting the concept of [minimum charge](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#minimum-charge) for document reads: "There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results."

Comment: Thank you for clearing up things. what if i run my query for the 10 documents, getting the ids out of it and add a .where("id", "==", true); to my second query which holds the information in my profilelikes subcollection?

Comment: Then you will reduce the number of reads to the number of docs corresponding to the where filter. And if there is no doc matching the filter it will count for one read.

Comment: Great, I think you made me finally understand when a read does count as a read. As conclusion this means it doesnt makes a difference if we are searching in any collection or subcollection which has 5 or 500.000 documents, only the final result of the query is counted as a read or atleast a single read if the result is 0 right?

Comment: Of course I did! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66456544/firestore-query-and-filtering-how-to-do-for-leaderboard Maybe you have a smart solution for displaying a leaderboard too?